# POST request with very long URLs in Google Appscript [URLFetchApp.fetch]

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make a POST request in Google AppScript with a long URL but facing the error `Limit Exceeded: URLFetch URL Length` as the URL length is limited to 2kB per call.

```
const url = "https://verylongurl.com";
  
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Oauthtoken " + accessToken,
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "followRedirects": true,
        "validateHttpsCertificates": true,
        "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        });
```

Is there any way I can get around this limit to make the POST request ?

Comment: @Tanaike what's wrong with just sending it as `payload` object? Will the error still occur?

Comment: @TheMaster I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About your question of `what's wrong with just sending it as payload object? Will the error still occur?`, do you want to send the long URL to the payload? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes. `{payload:"a=1&b=2"}` or  ``{payload:{a:1,b:2}}`` instead of  `https://url.com?a=1&b=2` Wouldn't that solve the issue of `Url size greater  than 2kb`?

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. I had thought that from `const url = "https://verylongurl.com"`, OP's URL is a long URL with no query parameter. For example, when OP's long URL was the URL including the query parameter, in the case of `{payload:"a=1&b=2"} or {payload:{a:1,b:2}}`, the data is sent as the form data. But in the case of `https://url.com?a=1&b=2`, the data is sent as the arguments. But, unfortunately, I'm not sure about the specification of the API OP wants to use. So, I'm not sure whether the query parameter can be used as the form data. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike I see. The [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73396511/1) contained a long query parameter. Now it only shows longurl.com. No problem..

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that the query parameter can be sent as the arguments.